# php: how to find numbers in string?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have some strings like:

```
some words 1-25 to some words 26-50
more words 1-10
words text and words 30-100
```

how can I find and get from string all of the "1-25" and the "26-50" and more

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it’s integers, match multiple digits: `\d+`. To match the whole range expression: `(\d+)-(\d+)`.

Maybe you also want to allow whitespace between the dash and the numbers:

```
(\d+)\s*-\s*(\d+)
```

And maybe you want to make sure that the expression stands free, i.e. isn’t part of a word:

```
\b(\d+)\s*-\s*(\d+)\b
```

`\b` is a zero-width match and tests for word boundaries. This expression forbids things
like “`Some1 -2text`” but allows “`Some 1-2 text`”.

Comment: can we talk i want your advice

Comment: i try:
preg_match_all("(\d+)\s*-\s*(\d+)","some words 1-25 to some words 26-50", $matches); 
It does not work

Comment: @motioz: You need to [enclose the regular expressions into delimiters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php), e.g. `/(\d+)\s*-\s*(\d+)/`. That's so common that it was not mentioned in the answer to keep the patterns more readable.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with regular expressions:

```
echo preg_match_all('/([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)/', 'some words 1-25 to some words 26-50 more words 1-10 words text and words 30-100', $matches);
4
print_r($matches);
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1-25
            [1] => 26-50
            [2] => 1-10
            [3] => 30-100
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 26
            [2] => 1
            [3] => 30
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 25
            [1] => 50
            [2] => 10
            [3] => 100
        )

)
```

For each range the first value is in array[1] and the second is in array[2] at the same index.

Answer (score 0):

**I think this line is enough**

```
preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","",$string);
```