# Saving numerics from a string

Tags: php

I'm looking to store all number's that occur alone in a string. The integers must occur on their own and be surrounded by white space.

Here's what I mean:

**Input**

> blah 5 blah bl3h 555 blah 123 blah a2b3 5030a

**Expected Output**

> [5], [555], [123]

Here's my attempted iterator that seems to group the current word correctly but adds nothing to the array

```
//$a = String
function numberReturn($a){

    $currWord;

    $numberArray = array();

    //Loop through string
    for($i = 0; $i < strlen($a); $i++){
        //Keep adding chars to current word
        $currWord .= $a[$i];


        //if white space check if current word is only numeric
        //if only numbers add it to array
        //when added, clear current word
        if(ctype_space($a[$i])){
            if(is_numeric($currWord)){
                $numberArray[] = $currWord;
            }
            $currWord = "";
        }
    }
    return $numberArray;
}
```

Comment: I was tempted to vote this page as a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9452234/php-how-to-find-numbers-in-string but I'll just leave the link as a reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you specifically need to use a loop, you can explode on space and filter out every substring that isn't made of digits.

```
$numbers = array_filter(explode(' ', $string), 'ctype_digit');
```

Comment: Small hint: it's also possible replace ```ctype_digit``` with ```is_numeric``` for negative & float numbers.

Comment: @user1597430 yes, but I'd advise anyone who does that to read the is_numeric documentation carefully. It has the potential of catching some other things that you might not want to consider as numbers.

Comment: @user1597430 negatives and floats do not seem to be an issue with the OP's task.  `integers` is stated in the question.  If the numbers may be negative, it is up to the OP to clarify.

Comment: Also some words about your comment "This way should be faster than what I suggested": your solution is 1.5x times faster than regexp you've commented.

Comment: @mickmackusa well, to be fair, the question does also say "numerics" and  "numbers", so who knows. :)

Comment: @user1597430 huh, I wouldn't have expected that. Interesting, but I don't think the result would be the same with a longer input string.

Comment: @mickmackusa I know that OP asked only for integers (at least he used numbers and integers together), however it's easy to improve this solution for float/negative support :)

Comment: Sorry, yes I was looking for purely positive integers. I also had to replace all new lines with spaces before exploding but it worked great! thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use [regular expressions](http://php.net/book.pcre) for this. The \d [escape sequence](http://php.net/regexp.reference.escape) will match all digits in the subject string.

For example:

```
<?php

function get_numerics ($str) {
    preg_match_all('/-?\.?(\d+((\.|,| )\d+)?)/', $str, $matches);
    return $matches[0];
}

$one = 'foo bar 4 baz (5 qux quux)';
$two = 'bar baz 2 bar';
$three = 'qux bar 12 quux (3 foo)';
$four = 'foo baz 3 bar (13 quux foo)';

print_r(get_numerics($one));
print_r(get_numerics($two));
print_r(get_numerics($three));
print_r(get_numerics($four));
```

https://3v4l.org/DiDBL

Comment: This way should be faster than what I suggested.

Comment: You need to add word boundaries so it doesn’t match “fo1400o” for example.

Comment: @ishegg i added it

Comment: No, @M0ns1f , don't ruin your answer with that edit.  Use: `/\b\d+\b/`

Comment: `\b(\d+)\b` will do it